# Laravel slow performance on pagination with large data

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 100k record in my `posts` table and 100k records in `users` table.

When i use `laravel's` pagination. it takes too long to return data...!

**Code:**

```
$posts = Post::join('users', 'posts.user_id', 'users.id')
    ->where('posts.status', '=', 1)
    ->where('users.status', '=', 1)
    ->paginate(10);
```

How can i fix this and got better performance?

**Note**

I have this problem also when i use `inRandomOrder()` on `$posts`

Comment: I think the query itself is the problem.

Comment: @GabMic True... When i use `Limit` in on mysql console it works fine. But question is how to fix in laravel

Comment: Do you have an index on `posts.user_id` and `users.id`?  If you run an `explain` on the select, does it indicate it's using the index?  100k records in both tables shouldn't be an issue especially if you have a limit on it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? get all posts with the status of 1, and the user who wrote the status?

Comment: @user3158900 Yes. also i have index on status field on both tables

Comment: The bottleneck for low page numbers is `select count(*) ...` which laravel will run in the background to calculate the number of pages.

Comment: @GabMic Posts with status 1 that wrote by users that has status 1

Comment: @PaulSpiegel So what is the solution?

Comment: What is the relation between them? in the models.

Comment: @SaeedVaziry It depends on your preferences. If you want to keep the frontend as it is, you might need to cache the count somewhere and implement a castom pagination.

Comment: Show us your tables please.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Laravel simplePaginate() method.
It will show only "Next" and "Previous" links, if that is enough for you.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination#usage

Comment: Yes i am using this one. But it isn't the solution